# Can I use google doc's to collect information from multiple users?

Tags: google-docs-api, office365, office365-apps

Currently I have a ASP.Net app, which display excel like form which collects data from user based on the template I setup. More I searched, I could very well use Google Doc's or Office 365 to create a excel like template and then send the link to users to enter the data. The users enter the data in the google doc template or office 365 template and I can have a common backend process which can query the docs and do what i want to do. I have couple of questions in this model

1. Can I create one template and send it to multiple users and they use the template to create their own document instead of overwriting my template?
2. Is it possible to add macros like excel in the docs/office 365?
3. I want the all the operation with zero foot print to client.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using [Google Forms](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/87809?p=forms_welcome&rd=1), you can create a form and send it as an email to your users, with their responses being automatically entered in a Google Docs spreadsheet. Then you can analyze that data in the spreadsheet using all the normal spreadsheet functionality (formulas, macros, etc).

Comment: Is it possible to create spreadsheet with macros in it and use that for sharing rather than forms?